# How do I click a control button with ID using AutoHotkey?

Tags: controls, autohotkey

How do I click a control button with ID using AutoHotkey?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried `Click` and `ControlClick`, but no luck!

```
ControlClick Button40

Click Button40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it some information about the window that the control is on. For example, to close the About screen in Notepad on Windows you could use

```
ControlClick, Button1, About Notepad ahk_class #32770
```

The format of the command from the docs is

```
ControlClick [, Control-or-Pos, WinTitle, WinText, WhichButton, ClickCount, Options, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]
```